# Running a Golang apache Beam pipeline on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, go, apache-beam

I created a simple golang Apache Beam pipeline and it is working well with `DirectRunner`. I tried to deploy it on a Spark cluster using the following command :
`./bin/spark-submit --master=spark://vm:7077 main.go --runner=SparkRunner --job_endpoint=localhost:8099 --artifact_endpoint=localhost:8098 --environment_type=LOOPBACK --output=/tmp/output`

Before submiting the application, i runned the `job_endpoint` using the following command :

`./gradlew :runners:spark:job-server:runShadow -PsparkMasterUrl=spark://localhost:7077`

The job fails on Spark with this error : `WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get main class in JAR with error 'null'.  Please specify one with --class.`

It seems that i need to specify the class argument but I do not understand what the error mean? can I get help ?

Comment: @ibzib Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) is a Spark utility that accepts either a Java JAR or a Python script. It doesn't know how to run Go programs.

I updated the Beam [Go quickstart guide](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-go/) with instructions for the Spark runner. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I run it using instructions porposed but i get the Following error :  `Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost:7077
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Comment: Passing the argument `-PsparkMasterUrl=spark://localhost:7077` to the job server means the job server will expect a Spark master to be listening on `localhost:7077`. If your Spark master is running somewhere else, like `vm:7077`, you need to change the Spark master url accordingly (i.e. `./gradlew :runners:spark:job-server:runShadow -PsparkMasterUrl=spark://vm:7077`).

Comment: I changed the Spark master url but now I get the following error :           .                             `Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up`

Comment: I assume the problem is the Beam job server is unable to reach the Spark master. Can you try running a Spark java job (like org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi) on your cluster using [spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)? If a Spark java job doesn't work, it means your problem is with your Spark cluster setup.